# How do I add two more lights to one cirucuit. The power is supplied to the first light?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have and old house and the light is supplied with power which then is connected to one switch. I want to add two more lights and have them run off the same switch. I connected as though the power was supplied to the switch at first but was the wrong assumption. Can I do this with just two conductor cables everywhere or do I need 3 conductors between the lights?

Answer (score 2):

You need a neutral and switched hot for each light. To get a neutral you really have 3 options:

- You can run a 14/2 wire from the existing light to the new light(s)
- You can run a new power supply into the switch, disconnecting the existing supply at the light (cap the wires). You can then run 14/2 from the switch to the new light(s).
- You can replace the existing wire between the light and switch with 14/3, so you can get neutral at the switch, then run 14/2 from the switch to the new light(s)

---

As an alternative, you could look into some of the smart switches on the market. Depending on what you use, there are several ways to do this, but essentially you can put your new lights on a new switch, then link the two switches together to form a virtual 3-way circuit and the end result is that either switch can control all the lights (there are many, many different ways to configure this as well, definable by programming the switches).

Comment: The 1st option is the easiest, connect the other lights in parallel to the current one. The existing light's neutral to each new light's neutral binding post. The light's other wire (switched hot) to each new light's other binding post. All 2 conductors. All other options needless complications IMO. But offering options is good.

Comment: @bcworkz Yeah but this is one of those difficult things to say without actually being there. The easiest approach really depends on accessibility from unfinished space (vs amount of damage you're willing to and capable of fixing), types of construction (drywall vs plaster vs brick), ability to route wires (eg, engineered beams or ductwork in the way, exterior insulated walls), proximity to another power source, etc.